# tracking loading times of 3rd party plugins in google analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am using a 3rd party plugin service (POWr.io) to add elements to our online store built using Shopify.  The plugin does not support script tags, so I was unable to add tags using the Google Tag Manager

I use a variety of plugins from this service, and I would like to be able to collect data on them, specifically measuring loading time for photo galleries, and setting up goals in Google Analytics for newsletter submissions.

I can add custom JS directly into the individual plugins (in this case a photo gallery), and I have loaded the Google Analytics Tracking Code Snippet successfully. I am currently using   ga('send', 'pageview'); but I think I need to use a different command to collect loading time, I have tried following what is [written here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings#overview)

However, I am not sure how to modify:

```
ga('send', 'timing', [timingCategory], [timingVar], [timingValue], [timingLabel], [fieldsObject]);
```

To get the results I need and into Google Analytics.

Likewise, for a form submission, I imagine I would need to use this:

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

But, again, not sure what how to modify this for my use in a plugin.

Any advice anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To measure timing events you need to create a timestamp when the event starts, another when it ends, and the difference between the two you pass in as timing value.

timingCategory, timingVar and timingLabel are just arbitrary strings that appear as dimensions in your reports (like category, action and label in  event tracking).

[timingValue is:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings#overview)

> timingValue   integer yes The number of milliseconds in elapsed time to
>   report to Google Analytics (e.g. 20).

With user timings GA is not doing the actual measuring for you, you need to determine the time yourself and put it in as a metric.